# How to solve Java EE EJB Glassfish error javax.naming.NamingException: Invocation exception: Got null ComponentInvocation?

Tags: jpa, jakarta-ee, netbeans, glassfish, ejb

I have a problem with creating a simple databse with EJB. I created a Web Project in Netbeans with Maven. I am using Glassfish 5 however the problem also occurs with glassfish 4.

Here are my classes.

Ui_model.java:

```
@Named("model")
@Stateless
public class Ui_model implements Serializable{

    @Inject 
    PizzaRepository pizzas;

    public Ui_model() {
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){

        Pizza one = new Pizza(1, "Pizza Margaritta", 4.5);
        Pizza two = new Pizza(2, "Pizza Napoli", 5);
        Pizza three = new Pizza(3, "Pizza Calzone", 6);

        pizzas.createDB(one);
        pizzas.createDB(two);
        pizzas.createDB(three);  
    }
}
```

PizzaRepository.java:

```
@Named
@ApplicationScoped
public class PizzaRepository implements Serializable{
    @PersistenceContext(unitName="Unit")
    protected EntityManager em;

    public void createDB(Pizza pizza){
        try{
            em.persist(pizza);
        }catch(RollbackException e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

    }
}
```

Pizza.java:

```
@Entity
public class Pizza implements Serializable{
    @Id
    int number;
    String name;
    double price;

    public Pizza(int number, String name, double price) {
        this.number = number;
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
    }
    public Pizza(){

    }
}
```

This is my persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.1"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="Unit" transaction-type="JTA">
        <jta-data-source>java:app/jdbc/testdb</jta-data-source>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <properties>
            <!-- database connection -->
            <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="drop-and-create" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

This is my glassfish-resources.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE resources PUBLIC "-//GlassFish.org//DTD GlassFish Application Server 3.1 Resource Definitions//EN" "http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-resources_1_5.dtd">
<resources>
    <jdbc-connection-pool allow-non-component-callers="false" 
                          associate-with-thread="false" 
                          connection-creation-retry-attempts="0" 
                          connection-creation-retry-interval-in-seconds="10" 
                          connection-leak-reclaim="false" 
                          connection-leak-timeout-in-seconds="0" 
                          connection-validation-method="auto-commit" 
                          datasource-classname="org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDataSource" 
                          fail-all-connections="false" idle-timeout-in-seconds="300" 
                          is-connection-validation-required="false" 
                          is-isolation-level-guaranteed="true" 
                          lazy-connection-association="false" 
                          lazy-connection-enlistment="false" 
                          match-connections="false" 
                          max-connection-usage-count="0" 
                          max-pool-size="32" 
                          max-wait-time-in-millis="60000" 
                          name="derby_net_testdb_usernamePool" 
                          non-transactional-connections="false" 
                          pool-resize-quantity="2" 
                          res-type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
                          statement-timeout-in-seconds="-1" 
                          steady-pool-size="8" 
                          validate-atmost-once-period-in-seconds="0" 
                          wrap-jdbc-objects="false">
        <property name="serverName" value="localhost"/>
        <property name="portNumber" value="1527"/>
        <property name="databaseName" value="testdb"/>
        <property name="User" value="username"/>
        <property name="Password" value="123456"/>
        <property name="URL" value="jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/testdb"/>
        <property name="driverClass" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver"/>
    </jdbc-connection-pool>
    <jdbc-resource enabled="true" 
                   jndi-name="java:app/jdbc/testdb" 
                   object-type="user" 
                   pool-name="java:app/derby_net_testdb_usernamePool"/>
</resources>
```

My project structure:
[image: My project structure:]

When I run this I get the following error:

[image]

The strange thing is that this still creates an empty table named Pizza in the testdb but with no entries. So it doesn't mean that the program is not finding the DB itself. I really don't know what to make of that error. The project was much bigger originally but I broke it down to get to the base problem and it doesn't get much easier than this. Still it doesn't work. I would appreciate any advice on how to fix it.

Edit:
asadmin list-jndi-entries prompts:

```
java:global: com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext
UserTransaction: com.sun.enterprise.transaction.startup.TransactionLifecycleService$2
__internal_java_app_for_app_client__testdb__java:app: com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext
concurrent: com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext
com.sun.enterprise.container.common.spi.util.InjectionManager: com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl
jms: com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext
ejb: com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext
jdbc: com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext
Command list-jndi-entries executed successfully.
```

asadmin list-jndi-entries --context jdbc prompts:

```
__default: org.glassfish.resourcebase.resources.api.ResourceProxy
__TimerPool: org.glassfish.resourcebase.resources.api.ResourceProxy
sample: org.glassfish.resourcebase.resources.api.ResourceProxy
Command list-jndi-entries executed successfully.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem by putting the glassfish.xml into an setup file in src. I also got help from a friend who gave me his files.

glassfish.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE resources PUBLIC "-//GlassFish.org//DTD GlassFish Application Server 3.1 Resource Definitions//EN" "http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-resources_1_5.dtd">
    <resources>
        <jdbc-connection-pool allow-non-component-callers="false" associate-with-thread="false" connection-creation-retry-attempts="0" connection-creation-retry-interval-in-seconds="10" connection-leak-reclaim="false" connection-leak-timeout-in-seconds="0" connection-validation-method="auto-commit" datasource-classname="org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDataSource" fail-all-connections="false" idle-timeout-in-seconds="300" is-connection-validation-required="false" is-isolation-level-guaranteed="true" lazy-connection-association="false" lazy-connection-enlistment="false" match-connections="false" max-connection-usage-count="0" max-pool-size="32" max-wait-time-in-millis="60000" name="derby_net_testdb_pizzaPool" non-transactional-connections="false" pool-resize-quantity="2" res-type="javax.sql.DataSource" statement-timeout-in-seconds="-1" steady-pool-size="8" validate-atmost-once-period-in-seconds="0" wrap-jdbc-objects="false">
            <property name="serverName" value="localhost"/>
            <property name="portNumber" value="1527"/>
            <property name="databaseName" value="testdb"/>
            <property name="User" value="username"/>
            <property name="Password" value="123456"/>
            <property name="connectionAttributes" value=";create=true" />
            <property name="URL" value="jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/testdb;create=true"/>
            <property name="driverClass" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver"/>
        </jdbc-connection-pool>
        <jdbc-resource enabled="true" jndi-name="jdbc/testdb" object-type="user" pool-name="derby_net_testdb_pizzaPool"/>
    </resources>

persistence.xml:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="Unit" transaction-type="JTA">
    <jta-data-source>jdbc/testdb</jta-data-source>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
      <!--<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/ModulDB"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="pizza"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="123456"/>-->
      <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="drop-and-create"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

However I then got an error Could not create stateless EJB because of the persist call. That I could resolve by not calling createDB() in the PostConstruct init(). I don't know why but it just didn't work with post construct. Now everything works properly so far. Thank you all very much.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that the `jdbc-resource pool-name` and the `jdbc-connection-pool name` do not match. The first has `java:app/` prefixed. Try to remove that.

See here for a minimal example: https://github.com/payara/Payara-Examples/blob/master/payara-micro/database-ping/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/glassfish-resources.xml

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't solve the problem. The same error still occurs.

Comment: Ok, I would try to bring your `resources.xml` as close as possible to the example I posted. Especially with regard to JNDI names. E.g. try to leave out the `java:app` namespace for the `jndi-name` (of course also in the `persistence.xml`).

Comment: I already tired that too. I only added the java:app bit in the first place because otherwise the DB is not found at all. So when I remove it too it can not find the DB.

Comment: OK, couldn't know what you already tried since it is not written in the description. Could you please extend your description by the output of the command `asadmin list-jndi-entries` and `asadmin list-jndi-entries --context jdbc`

Comment: Ok. I put the output in the description. Thank you for your help so far :)

Comment: And what is listed under context `__internal_java_app_for_app_client__testdb__java:app`?

Comment: Could you please explain how I look that up :)? I don't really know and today was the first time I used asadmin so far.

Comment: `asadmin list-jndi-entries --context __internal_java_app_for_app_client__testdb__java:app` I think your datasource is hidden behind this context.

Comment: it prompts: `jdbc: com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext                                                 
Command list-jndi-entries executed successfully.`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204180/discussion-between-christoph-john-and-levi).